# Fusion piechart data not showing (No data to display)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, codeigniter, fusioncharts

I have written a sample code to display the sample pie chart data in codeigniter but i get No data to display in the display div, the controller function is ok is returning the correct xml, suggestions

My controller function

```
   function getpieData() {
        $FC = $this->Charts();
        $strXML = "caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units' animation=1";
        $FC->setChartParams($strXML);
        $strQuery = $this->db->get('Factory_Master');
        $result = $strQuery->result();
        if ($result) {
            foreach ($result as $data) {
                $strQuery = $this->db->query("select sum(Quantity) as TotOutput from Factory_Output where FactoryId=$data->FactoryId");
                $result2 = $strQuery->result();
                foreach ($result2 as $ors) {
                    $FC->addChartData( $ors->TotOutput,"label=".$data->FactoryName);     
                }

                print $FC->getXML();
            }
        }
    }
```

The xml returned

```
<chart caption='&apos;Factory Output report&apos; subCaption=&apos;By Quantity&apos; pieSliceDepth=&apos;30&apos; showBorder=&apos;1&apos; formatNumberScale=&apos;0&apos; numberSuffix=&apos; Units&apos; animation=1'  ><set  value='644' label='Factory 1'  /><set  value='2644' label='Factory 2'  /><set  value='1252' label='Factory 3'  /></chart>
```

My Html

```
 <script>
     function drawPieChart(chartSWF, strXML, chartdiv) {
    //Create another instance of the chart.
    var chart = new FusionCharts(chartSWF, "FactorySum", "600", "300", false, false); 
    chart.setDataXML(strXML);
    chart.render(chartdiv);
   }
   $().ready(function){
    $.get("<?php echo base_url();?>main_dashboard/getpieData/",function(data) {
        drawPieChart("<?php echo base_url();?>charts/Pie3D.swf", data, "gen-chart- render");
    });

}
</script>   


<div id="gen-chart-render">

                    <center>

                    </center>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the XML generated from the controller is malformed.

If you are using $FC->setChartParams() method to set the attributes, you would need to pass them as a single string with delimiter separated list of attributes.

Ref. Code:

```
 $strXML = "caption=Factory Output report;subCaption=By Quantity;pieSliceDepth=30; showBorder=1;formatNumberScale=0;numberSuffix=Units;animation=1";
 $FC->setChartParams($strXML);
```

For more details, please refer [Link](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/fusioncharts-php-class/Functions.html).